# Copying Columns within a library in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to copy two different columns into two different named columns in a sharepoint library(doc type -> acc doc type & series -> series name) Currently I have been highlighting and then using the drag option into the second column, but that is very inefficient as you cannot use it when you highlight the entire column, as well as there often being several hundred files per library. Is there an easier way to copy the columns? Much appreciated!

Note: the new columns im trying to copy them into are global columns so i believe making new ones will not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is `Datasheet` view (SharePoint 2010 and earlier versions), or, in SharePoint 2013 (which it sounds like you are using) it is called `Quick Edit`.

In any document library, click on the library tab in the ribbon and then `Quick Edit`.  This will take you to a view that allows you to manipulate the metadata as you would in excel, e.g., copying and pasting large amounts of data at a time.

Comment: I have currently been using the quick edit, however sharepoint does not allow the full range of effectiveness that excel offers. With quick edit, you can only copy small amounts of data at a time, and it is very inefficient.

Comment: How many rows do you need to edit?  Can you increase the Item Limit in the view you are using?

Comment: sometimes its up to a thousand, no the limit is always 100